# Can't find Element On instagram Automation

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, instagram

I am trying to make a automatic account creator on instagram but unable to select the birthdate...

Here is the code

```
monthx = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/span/span[1]/select"
    month_button = driver.ind_element(By.XPATH,monthx)
    print("found the month button")
    select = Select(month_button)
    select.select_by_value(str(month))
    sleep(1)
    print("selected and input month")
    day_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
        '//*[@id="mount_0_0_Lr"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/span/span[2]/select')
    select = Select(day_button)
    select.select_by_value(str(day))
    sleep(1)
    year_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mount_0_0_Lr"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/span/span[3]/select')
    select = Select(year_button)
    select.select_by_value(str(year))
    sleep(2)
```